# recursive file & folder sharing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

I have a folder on a Windows 7 Home Professional PC that I'd like to share with the network. I've gone through the process of sharing the folder:

Right Click on the folder -> Share with -> Homegroup (read)

The folder will now be visible, but some files seem to still be not explicitly shared.

The still have the little lock icon in the bottom left:

[image: non shared item]

I can right click and share the file explicitly, but there are 2 problems:

1. I have lots of files that I want shared (think...media center PC)
2. New content is generated in to this shared folder and for some
   reason (I don't know why) the new content is not shared despite its
   parent folder being shared.

Is there a setting in Windows 7 to recursively share all files in a given folder, or do I need to write a script, but a tool, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock (padlock) overlay icon appears for files/folders which are private, but located under a non-private directory.

This procedure should correct the permissions of the entire folder :

1. Right click in Windows Explorer on the shared folder and select **Properties**
2. Go to the tab **Security**
3. Click on the **Advanced** button at the bottom.
4. Click on **Change Permission**
5. Ensure that the following accounts are listed: Users, HomeUsers, Everyone.
   If one is missing, click on **Add**, then **Advanced**, then **Find now**,
   select it and press OK twice.
6. Check the options **Include inheritable permissions from this object’s parent**
   and **Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions with this object**
7. Click on **OK**

The three accounts I listed above in step 5 might be an over-kill.
You could try this procedure first while skipping this step.

Answer (score 0):

if that would not work, you might use the c:\users\public folder (documents \ public documents in libraries) and I guess everything should be set right in this one by default.